# Intel Rapid Storage Technology (HDD-Cache on SSD) compromising Truecrypt?

Tags: ssd, encryption, truecrypt

I run a Dell Vostro with a HDD, accelerated by Intel Rapid Storage Technology caching on the (much smaller) SSD. I intend to encrypt all partitions with TrueCrypt, but I have no access to whatever is happening on the SSD - it is some sort of a 20GB-blackbox full of MRU-Data.

Does anyone know how IRST and TC work together? Does IRST cache the data exactly as read/written to HDD (i.e. encrypted) or os TC on layers closer to the hardware, i.e. delivering decrypted data to IRST to cache?

Answer (score 1):

RST only caches data that is written to the hard disk. If you don't store decrypted data on the hard disk, you won't wind up with decrypted data on the SSD.